# How to add multi row headers/column names to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to represent the table data in a data frame where the table is having multiple headers spanning more than one row as shown below example.

[image: multi-header table]

With data frames, I am able to set only one row of header or column names as below

```r
colnames(df) <- c("col1", "col2", ...)
```

Is there a way to give multiple headers or column names to a data frame 
or is there a better data structure or package available to represent such data structures?

Comment: What is your end goal? Where do you want to publish the table?

Comment: i want to do query on the data frame object like select required rows and columns with multi header names.
In python, the pandas data frame is having an option of setting multiheader to the data frame object. and by which user can select the column giving the column names.
looking for a similar one in R

Comment: Using a prefix to your column names might be one way. Then you can query with something like: `iris[iris$Sepal.Length < 4.5, startsWith(names(iris), "Petal")]`

Comment: but i am not appending the headers in a single cell. like the "Organization1" and "id" are in two different rows which has to be treated as headers.
i prefer not to merge them as "Organization1_id" (if this is what you are assuming)

Comment: If the reason you want to do this is subsetting you could still do that: `Id_org1`, `Dept_org1`, `Id_org2`, etc.

Comment: In my case the readability could be a problem when i have like 5 row headers as column names. They will be appeneded with underscore to a long string.

and i might even have few columns with empty names, im not sure if that will be a problem to be represented in a data frame

Comment: Maybe  a list of data.frames would be more helpful. Don't know just brining up ideas.

Comment: the flextable package allows you to mae tables that have this structure: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html

Comment: @RAB is there a possibility of selecting specific data using row and column names in this flextable objects?
i went through the documentation, didnt find anything related to querying though..